# Haskell (Maybe, x, Maybe y, Maybe z) -> Maybe (x,y,z)

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I have a set of Haskell IO bound calls that return Maybe Z, Maybe Y, Maybe Z, where X /= Y /= Z.

I would like a function that returns Just (X,Y,Z) where ALL are Just n, or else Nothing.

A naive implementation would be

```
fn :: (Maybe x, Maybe y, Maybe z) -> Maybe (x,y,z)
fn (Just x, Just y, Just z) = Just (x,y,z)
fn _ = Nothing
```

but I'm wondering is there a more elegant solution? Perhaps some kind of mapping?

As far as I can see, the more usual

```
let x = do x <- fn1
           y <- fn2
           z <- fn3
           return (x,y,z) :: Maybe (X,Y,Z)
```

isn't going to work because fn1-3 are IO bound?

thanks.

Comment: Did you try the "more usual" approach? Did it work? If no, what went wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to specify the output type. You can work with:

```
f :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m c -> m (a, b, c)
f mx my mz = do
    x <- mx
    y <- my
    z <- mz
    return (x, y, z)
```

But here you can work with:

```
f :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f c -> f (a, b, c)
f fa fb fc = (,,) <$> fa <*> fb <*> fc
```

or as [@RobinZigmond says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70265726/haskell-maybe-x-maybe-y-maybe-z-maybe-x-y-z/70265747?noredirect=1#comment124210960_70265747), with [**`liftA3 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c -> d) -> f a -> f b -> f c -> f d`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA3):

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA3)

f :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f c -> f (a, b, c)
f = liftA3 (,,)
```